# Source for the order of the aleph-beis?

Tags: sources-mekorot, aleph-bet-letters

What is the source for the Hebrew alphabet being in the order that it is? Meaning I realize that there are perhaps several sources that Aleph is the first letter, beis is the second etc, but is there any source or combination of sources which lists out the entire aleph-bet in the order in which we have it today?

[possibly related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21758/was-the-hebrew-alphabet-also-given-with-the-tablets-and-law)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9386/759

Comment: Good question!  The earliest abecedaries(scribal exercises), the Tel Zayit for example, have been dated to the 11th-10th century BCE.  An interesting thing about a couple of them found so far is that they have the ayin and peh in reverse order--so quite possibly, in answer to the Eicha question, is that the alphabet might have started out that way.  The later abecedaries all have them in the correct order.

Comment: @Gary good point, that is most definitely the simplest answer to the Eicha dilemma!

Comment: @Bach - there was an article on this subject in Biblical Archaeology Review a few years ago that has the basics of the theory: http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/biblical-topics/bible-versions-and-translations/can-abecedaries-be-used-to-date-the-book-of-psalms/

Comment: @Bach - unfortunately, for the actual, more detailed article, they want you to sign up for their archive access.  Phooey! ...But at least that page I linked has the basics of it.

Comment: @Bach - this is FREE and I think is the actual article:   http://thetorah.com/pe-before-ayin-in-biblical-pre-exilic-acrostics/

Comment: @Gary thanx, lots of new info there.

Answer (score 7):

[*Bavli*, *Shabas* 104](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=330&size=1), is such a source. Plus, there are a number of chapters of *Tanach* written as alphabetical acrostics (albeit with [omissions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7084) or [a slightly different order](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9386) in some cases): specifically, Pslams 25, 34, 37, 111, 112, 119, and 145; Proverbs 31; and most of Lamentations.